# Ethers.js - Error: invalid BigNumber string

Tags: erc-20, ethers.js, error, erc-20-approve, bignumber

I am trying to approve a larger amount of erc-20 tokens (it has 18 decimals).

```
await token.connect(signer).approve(contractAddress, BigNumber.from((1000*(tenToPowerOf18Digits)).toString())) :
```

If I try to approve more than 999 tokens, it gives me this err

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: invalid BigNumber string (argument="value", value="1e+21", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=bignumber/5.5.0)
```

Can anyone help me with this issue? How can I approve more than 999 tokens?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that the `toString` of the number will convert it to a scientific representation which cannot be interpreted by the BigNumber.

The cleanest way to get around this is to use BigNumber when adding the decimals:

```js
const decimals = 18;
const input = 999;
const amount = BigNumber.from(input).mul(BigNumber.from(10).pow(decimals));
```

Another way is using ethers to parse this:

```js
const decimals = 18;
const input = "999"; // Note: this is a string, e.g. user input
const amount = ethers.utils.parseUnits(input, decimals)
```

Comment: Thanks this worked and really helped!